# Edx course/ Python basic/reverse a string using pop(),while,insert

Tags: python-3.x

It's a simple question to make the code print reverse string of input string using pop(), while, insert. I guess there must be easier and simpler way to make it, but I wonder why my code has wrong results. I ask your help!

```
string=input('enter the string you want to reverse: ')
l_string=list(string)
print(l_string)
l_r_string=[]

while l_string:
    l_r_string.insert(-1,l_string.pop())
    print(l_rstring) #to check how the string is made up every step

print(''.join(l_r_string))
```

I think there is a problem in index part of insert. I just set as '-1' to save it in reverse order. However, results came out like this.

```
enter the string you want to reverse: 1234
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['4']
['3', '4']
['3', '2', '4']
['3', '2', '1', '4']
3214
```

Comment: `.insert(-1, ...)` is inserting at the next-to-last position.  To insert at the end, use `.append(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite figure out why the insert method is doing that. My guess would be that it for some reason keeps 4 at the last element and then it just has to insert each element before that, but another way to use while, insert, and pop to do that is to use len(l) instead of -1 for the index. So use:

```
    while l_string:
        l_r_string.insert(len(l_r_string),l_string.pop())
        print(l_r_string)
```

That will insert each one at the end of the list.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I could fix the problem with it!

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
s[::-1]
```

It iterates the string backward.

Answer (score 1):

```
some_numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]

rev_string = []

while len(some_numbers):

    rev = some_numbers.pop(0)

    rev_string.insert(0,rev)


print(rev_string)
```